# Stars visible during ascent?

Tags: space-shuttle, stars, ascent

Did any shuttle astronaut indicate at what altitude they were first able to see the stars during an ascent to orbit at sunrise?

[Yeagar seeing the stars in *The Right Stuff*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYEKSqa41q8).  For illustration purposes only, I know its fiction.  If it is not an appropriate addition to the question leave a comment (rather than downvoting) and I will remove the clip.

I thought I recalled seeing a star just after sunset (still a blue sky) at zenith during a college observatory session.  An [astronomy SE discussion](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33668/seeing-a-star-near-zenith-around-sunset?noredirect=1#comment63951_33668) indicates that is possible.  So if an astronaut was at a window on the shadow side of a vehicle during ascent, at sunrise it seems reasonable to assume that astronaut could have seen stars.

Comment: Not necessarily an answer but seeing stars in space during daytime takes time because your eyes need to adjust.

Comment: There are several questions on the site about both cameras and eyes being able to sense stars. This question complements the others. I believe it will be necessary to specify that the sun must remain visible somewhere in the sky though, otherwise a launch just before sundown will result in visible stars as night falls.

Comment: They were not able to see the stars at any altitude while being on the dayside of Earth. Their eyes could not adapt to darkness while the surface of Earth lighted by the Sub was visible to them.

Comment: @Uwe If the launch took place at sunrise, and once they left the atmosphere they couldn't see starts if they looked away from both the Sun and the Earth?

Comment: Only if there is no bright sunlid object (no Earth, no Sun, no Shuttle parts) within their view and after some minutes for their eyes to adapt fully to darkness

Comment: That star you saw just after sunset (still a blue sky) at zenith was probably the planet Venus.

Comment: @Uwe When is Venus 90°+ from the Sun?  I thought it was never much more than 20°.

Comment: If the bright star at zenith was not Venus, what about Jupiter or Mars? Those planets are much brighter than the brightest star Sirius. See the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude).

Comment: @Uwe As I remember it we had just looked at it through the university's telescope.  I don't recall it being a planet.

Comment: @Uwe I checked Stellarium for the location, the year, and month this happened.  By the time the sun set Jupiter was below the horizon and Mars was 20° above the horizon.  We were looking directly overhead when we saw the star naked eye.